# Can someone please translate this picture for me? Please i need help!

Tags: character-identification

[image: **Hi guys, can someone please help me translate this tatto to english? I need your help!**]

I have this picture and I know that the last symbol means sentenced, but i don't know what the rest of them are, or even what is the meaning. Please help! :)

Comment: The first one means "after" or "post." The last two together means "trial." I never saw these three put together like this. Maybe some dialects speak that way.

Comment: There might be another word preceding the above sentense.  It is a common sentence in ancient time as "秋後審判" - Trials after Fall / Autumn (秋).

Comment: If that is the case, that is what people say when they swear vengeance.

Comment: Thank you so much, every comment is useful. Yes there is another word preceding those two, I'm gonna try to get the picture of everything. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1):

後 - after, or late

審判 - judge, or trial (it does not have the mean of sentence)

Answer (score 1):

審判 is made up of two parts.

審: going through trial proceedings, also carries the meaning of auditing

判: issuing a verdict

The two combined means "to judge/ judgement"
I agree with the comment that there is possibly another character preceeding these three.

Answer (score 1):

I think 秋後審判 is not correct. The custom is 秋后问斩，or 秋后算账， not 秋后审判.
Without full context, can't determine what's the meaning. Maybe it's just a joke like 先枪毙，后审判（execute you before trial）. You should check another arm if there is 先枪毙 attached.

Answer (score 0):

秋後審判

Trial in late autumn.

The meaning is quite close to "Let's wait and see." or "I will revenge somehow sometime."